# Number correction - How many twelves has 132?

Tags: grammatical-number

Should it be "How many twelves have 132?"

Notes: The question intends to find out how many 12's are there in number 132? answer being 12 x 11 = 132 or 11.

Comment: How many twelves does 132 have?

Comment: How many twelves are there in 132?

Comment: Or, in primary-school speak of my era - "How many twelves go into 132?"

Comment: Also the title of this Quora question: https://www.quora.com/How-many-5-are-there-in-25

Comment: See: http://www.homeschoolmath.net/teaching/f/dividing_fractions_2.php

Comment: what is 132 divided by 12?

Comment: Thanks. I was sure the book had grammatical error. Thanks all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you wouldn't say "132 *are* my lucky number".

Is this context any different from "132 has 11 12's"?

"132" here is just a numeral on its own and not counting anything, and so it is singular. By this reasoning, the question should be "How many 12's has 132?"